# The function (dispath) does not work when I press the button

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

Its a action-function that works with redax (it works perfectly because I used it)

```
export const fetchCategory = () => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    try {
      dispatch(settingsSlice.actions.settingsFetching());
      const response = await request("/category/getAll", "POST", {});
      dispatch(settingsSlice.actions.settingsFetchingSuccess(response));
    } catch (e) {
      dispatch(settingsSlice.actions.settingsFetchingError(e));
    }
  };
};
```

I need that when the button is pressed, a request is made to the server and the state is updated

Here is the function that is executed when you click on the button :

```
    const buttonHandler = async () => {
    await request("/category/create", "POST", {
      newCategory: {
        label: form.categoryLabel,
        limit: form.categoryLimit,
      },
    });
    setForm(initialState);
    fetchCategory();
  };
```

I checked, the form is sent to the backend and everything works fine except for this "fetchCategory"

I already tried to do this using useEffect

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetchCategory();
  }, [Button , buttonHandler]);
```

i tried to install different dependencies but no result. How can this problem be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `dispatch` the action!

Your `fetchCategory` function is a "thunk action creator".  Calling `fetchCategory()` creates the thunk action, but doesn't do anything with it. You need to call `dispatch(fetchCategory())` to execute the action.

```
const buttonHandler = async () => {
    await request("/category/create", "POST", {
      newCategory: {
        label: form.categoryLabel,
        limit: form.categoryLimit,
      },
    });
    setForm(initialState);
--> dispatch(fetchCategory()); <--
};
```